# Devise: how to get user password from db

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm writing cucumber tests for user login.

I have such scenario background, that adds user to database

```
User.create!(

    :email => email,

    :password => password,

    :password_confirmation => password

    )
```

So, why in my sequential step, I get @user.password nil?

```
  @user = User.find_by :email => "some@email.com"

  ...

  fill_in('Email', :with => @user.email)

  fill_in('Password', :with => @user.password)
  ...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Devise initially stores the original password by encrypting it. The `encrypted_password`(field name in your model) gets stored in the database.

Now, when you call `User.find_by :email => "some@email.com"` the `password` field is non existing.`password` is not a field in the model User. Its an instance variable present in the model which is only set when you submit the `login/sign up` form. In your case, you are trying to access password field before `log in` hence, the instance variable is not set and you get `password` as nil.

If you want more details, you can check the actual implementation of [Devise password](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/25726becdddf64f001c37a36d47c0c8595b5733c/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [devise cucumber test](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Test-with-Cucumber) wiki page for more info.

As Kirti points out you don't have access to the password as an attribute in the User model, especially not in plain text.

If you're testing the login keep the password field around as a variable or create the user in that test.

```
Given /^I am a new, authenticated user$/ do
  email = 'testing@man.net'
  password = 'secretpass'
  User.create!(
    :email => email,
    :password => password,
    :password_confirmation => password
  )

  visit '/users/sign_in'
  fill_in "user_email", :with => email
  fill_in "user_password", :with => password
  click_button "Sign in"

end
```

If you really need to look up your user later (`@user = User.find_by`) and fill in the password then you'll need to keep your password as a variable outside the scope of the tests.